# Vector Parallelogram, Finding position vector and angle

Tags: vectors

ABCD is a parallelogram. The position vectors of A,B and C are given by 
A= $\ 2i+j+3k $ ,$\ B =3i-2j $ , $\ C= i-j-2k $, respectively.
Find the position vector of D and calculate the angle ABC.

My working
vector of $\ D = A+B+C $
            = .............

I know how to calculate 2d vector angle but i do not know how to do in 3d vectors

Comment: Opposite sides of parallelogram are equal in length. And find $\vec {AB},\vec {BC}$ to find the angle.

Comment: You find the angle the same way that you might in 2-D: take the dot product and divide by the lengths.

Comment: Are you sure that $D$ is the sum of the other vectors?